# Are humorous comments acceptable?

Tags: discussion, comments

I know there's a question, asking [whether humorous questions are acceptable](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/should-we-allow-humour-oriented-questions), and the majority have voted no.

I would like to know if humorous comments are acceptable.  I know these are all serious questions, but when someone asks a question like "Can anyone escape hell?"  I find it hard not to mention Chuck Norris.

Christians are supposed to be happy people, right??

Looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit of humor is an important part of building a community around a site like this. As long as it doesn't go overboard, there is nothing wrong with the occasional witty comment.

That said, don't be surprised if people think Chuck Norris jokes are getting a bit old.

Also, remember that religion is something that many people take very personally. It's very easy to offend someone if you start making fun of their beliefs, so keep that in mind.

See also: [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: Completely agree, especially about *Chuck Norris* jokes, which, if they ever were funny, are not anymore...

Comment: @Wikis, Chuck Norris has such an unbeatable sense of humor, he still thinks they're funny.

Comment: @PaulDraper: I fear you may have proved my point...

Comment: @Wikis, I believe I did :P

Answer (score 2):

I think humorous comments are fine... as long as they are made as comments and not answers.  This might be the one area where slashdot's ability to "moderate as funny" would be a nice addition to certain answers (though a humorous answer which isn't meant to be serious is opposed to the purpose of the StackExchange sites).